# Page Fetch: Redirect Error on Google Search Console - Getting error on some new pages but not on others

Tags: seo, google-search-console, search-engine-indexing, technical-seo

So, I know there's been a few iterations of this same question with this particular Google Search Console indexing error, but after sifting through a few of these, I couldn't find anyone having the same issue.

I run a blog for an alcohol delivery service, and we created these 5 recipe blogs:

- Green Tea Shot Without Sour Mix: https://blog.saucey.com/green-tea-shot-without-sour-mix-recipe/
- Traditional White Russian: https://blog.saucey.com/traditional-white-russian-recipe/
- Low Sugar Tequila Sunrise: https://blog.saucey.com/low-sugar-tequila-sunrise-recipe/

*(We also created a Ramos Gin Fizz & Vegan White Russian Recipe in same format but did not want to spam with links.)*

All 5 of these recipes were written, designed, and published in the same way (and on the same day).

So far, I've only been able to get the Green Tea Shot & Traditional White Russian recipes to be indexed. But even this isn't perfect - the Green Tea Shot has all the enhancements it should, while the Traditional Russian is only indexed with an AMP enhancement.

**Green Tea Recipe:**

[image: Green Tea Shot recipe blog with all the enhancements]

**Traditional White Russian Recipe:**

[image: Traditional White Russian Recipe without enhancements]

The other recipe blogs are coming back with the same "Page Fetch: Redirect Error."

**Here's an example on our Tequila Sunrise recipe:**

[image: Low-Sugar Tequila Sunrise Recipe]

I tried a few basic fixes, like:

- Updated all plugins & Wordpress site
- Reviewed sitemap to ensure URLs were appearing the same way as they were published, with the "/" at the end
- Reviewed redirections and ensured these recipes were not being redirected elsewhere by accident

To make matters more confusing for myself, when I test the live URL through GSC, it would seem that everything is right with it. I understand that this test is different than the actual crawling, but it's made it difficult to know where to go to fix this.

**Here's the same Tequila Sunrise recipe in a live test on GSC:**
[image: Tequila Sunrise recipe in live test mode]

Any thread or direction to go in to potentially fix these errors would be greatly appreciated!

Please let me know if I can provide more information.

Comment: I don't think this is related to the redirect error, but your server is returning multiple `vary` headers.  I see three of them with `curl --head https://blog.saucey.com/low-sugar-tequila-sunrise-recipe/`.  You should fix that so that there is only one.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, either the link of the Referring Page or the Internal Link in the Referring Page is HTTP instead of HTTPS. This also causes a Redirect. Check that.

One more thing, don't go to the Validation. Test the live URL and then, Request for the Indexing first once you check all the Links are HTTPS. Validation takes time.

Also, Google AMPs Index the page way faster than the Web Crawler. So, that's not an issue.